# Get next item from model

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm have created `GridView`, which delegates custom objects (`Item`) and its model is derived from `QSortFilterProxyModel`. Currently, whenever I click on an item in `GridView`, it show some info about it, but currently I am trying to control it with keyboard arrows, so I need to help with function, which gets next/previous item.

I have managed to think out some solutions:

- Get index of currently selected item in `GridView`, which I managed to do with:

  `console.log(slabItemContainer.contentItem.data[index])`, but I didn't manage out how to get delegate back from index (because I don't need `QQuickItem`, but I need pointer to `Item`). I have set role name for `Item` as a `"item"`, so whenever I write line by `console.log(item)`, it shows me right object, but I didn't manage to get it from `QQuickItem` by index.
- Get custom object from model derived by `QSortFilterProxyModel`

I have tried to get some kind of `QList` from my model, but I don't know how to access data. My model contains pointer to currently selected `Item`, so I've tried to get whole list from my model, then find currently selected item and then set next, but I didn't even created list, because I don't know, how to access it.
I have tried to use `mapToSource()`, but it didn't worked out.

`QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(0,0, QModelIndex());
     qDebug() << mapToSource(modelIndex);`

Clicking on `Item` in `GridView` prints `Item(0x2d508408)`, this prints me `QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,ItemModel(0x2d528210))`, but again, I don't know how to get data from it.

Does anyone have experience with it? How should I get next item by current item?

Thanks for your help!

//EDIT:

**Filter.h**

```
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include "Item.h"

class MyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Item* currentDetailView READ currentDetailView WRITE setFilterCurrentDetailView NOTIFY currentDetailViewChanged)

public:
    ItemFilterSortModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    //! Return true, if entity matches with filter conditions
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const;

    //! Returns Item to load into view
    Item * currentDetailView() const {return currentDetailView_;}

    //! Set up currently showing detail of Item
    Q_INVOKABLE void setFilterCurrentDetailView(Item *ItemToView);

    Q_INVOKABLE Item * getFilterNextDetailView();

    Q_INVOKABLE Item * getFilterPrevDetailView();

signals:
    currentDetailViewChanged();

private:
    Item *currentDetailView_;
};
```

**Filter.cpp**

```
#include "MyModel.h"

ItemFilterSortModel::ItemFilterSortModel(QObject *parent)
    : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{

}

bool ItemFilterSortModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    QModelIndex modelIndex = sourceModel()->index(source_row, 0, source_parent);

    //Checking conditions for displaying Item into gridview
    return (foo(sourceModel()->data(modelIndex,confidenceRole).toDouble()));
}

Item *ItemFilterSortModel::getFilterNextDetailView()
{
    QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(0,0, QModelIndex());
    qDebug() << mapToSource(modelIndex);
}

Item *ItemFilterSortModel::getFilterPrevDetailView()
{

}
```

**GridView.qml**

```
GridView {    
            model: slabGridModel.filterModel
            delegate: Item{
                height: slabItemContainer.cellHeight - 15
                width: slabItemContainer.cellWidth - 15
            }
            Action {
                 shortcut: "Right"
                 onTriggered: model.getFilterNextDetailView()
            }
        }
```

//EDIT:

This happen to screen when right arrow key is pressed
[image: What happens to screen when right arrow key is pressed]

//EDIT:

**ItemModel.h**

```
#include "Item.h"
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

class ItemModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // ---- PUBLIC METHODS ----
    //! Deletes items in list
    ~ItemModel();

    //! Returns number of items in list
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    //! Exposes data of Items to QML by their roles
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    //! Appends the Item into Item list
    void appendItem(Item * Item);

    //! Sets up role names for exposing them to QML
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

    //! Returns list of all available Items
    QList<Item *> getItemList() const { return ItemList_; }

private:
    // ---- PRIVATE ATTRIBUTES ----
    QList<Item *> ItemList_;
};
```

**ItemModel.cpp**

```
#include "ItemModel.h"

ItemModel::~ItemModel(){
    qDeleteAll(ItemList_);
    ItemList_.clear();
}

int ItemModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
    return parent.isValid() ? 0 : ItemList_.size();
}

QVariant ItemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::UserRole:
        {
            Item *Item =  ItemList_[index.row()];
            return QVariant::fromValue(Item);
        }
        break;
    default:
        return QVariant();
        break;
    }
}

void ItemModel::appendItem(Item *Item)
{
    ItemList_.append(Item);
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> ItemModel::roleNames() const{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[Qt::UserRole] = "item";
    return roles;
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: You want it from the model or from the view?

Comment: @eyllanesc Added

Comment: @derM I don't know and I don't care, I just simply want to "rotate" items with arrows

Comment: @Brykyz You want to get the QModelIndex or the Sample, where do you want to get it in C ++ or QML ?, you could show an example of input and indicate the output you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc Both, in C++ the pointer to current Item will change, and currently viewed Item will change, I have added picture

Comment: @Brykyz I need more details of your model to implement the C ++ part, you could show the model.

Comment: @Brykyz What property do you want to change on the C ++ side?

Comment: @eyllanesc  Item *currentDetailView_;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149966/exposing-qlistcustomobj-to-qml) since I think you're using it as the basis of your code , we can obtain the following element in QML since as you use a proxy the following is relative on the model side, since as you indicate in the figure the following is a visual concept:

**itemfiltersortmodel.h**

```
#ifndef FILTERPROXYMODEL_H
#define FILTERPROXYMODEL_H

#include "item.h"

#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include <QDebug>

class ItemFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Item* currentItem READ currentItem WRITE setCurrentItem NOTIFY currentItemChanged)
public:
    using QSortFilterProxyModel::QSortFilterProxyModel;
    Item *currentItem()
    {
        return mCurrentItem;
    }
    void setCurrentItem(Item *currentItem)
    {
        qDebug()<<currentItem;
        if(mCurrentItem == currentItem)
            return;
        mCurrentItem = currentItem;
        emit currentItemChanged();
    }
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
    {
        // foo process
        return true;
    }
signals:
    void currentItemChanged();
private:
    Item *mCurrentItem;
};

#endif // FILTERPROXYMODEL_H
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    GridView {
        id: gv
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: manager.filterModel
        property int nextIndex : mod(currentIndex+1, count)
        property int previousIndex : mod(currentIndex-1, count)
        property var currentModelItem
        onCurrentModelItemChanged: model.currentItem = currentModelItem
        delegate:
            Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            property var view: GridView.view
            property bool isCurrentItem: index === view.currentIndex
            property bool isPreviousItem : index === view.nextIndex
            property bool isNextItem : index === view.previousIndex
            color: isCurrentItem ? "red" : isNextItem ? "green"  : isPreviousItem ? "blue" : "yellow"
            rotation: isCurrentItem ? 180 : isNextItem ? 90  : isPreviousItem? -90  : 0
            onIsNextItemChanged: if(isNextItem) view.currentModelItem = modelData
            Text {
                text: modelData.getVar
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/50770689/6622587
    function mod(n, p){
        var r = n % p;
        return r < 0 ? r + p : r;
    }
    Action {
        shortcut: "Right"
        onTriggered: gv.currentIndex = mod(gv.currentIndex + 1, gv.count)

    }
    Action {
        shortcut: "Left"
        onTriggered: gv.currentIndex = mod(gv.currentIndex - 1, gv.count)
    }
}
```

[image]

Colors:

- previous: blue
- current: red
- next: green

You can find the complete code in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51364623).

Comment: That's good, but I want to change it in C++ too - set currently viewing item (pointer at it) to filter attribute, as I want to move only in filtered list. Something like setFilterCurrentDetailView(index + 1) in GridView, but setFilterCurrentDetailView have Item * as parameter.